# Add hours during check-in process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

In TFS workitems we have several fields for tracking time: **Original Estimate**, **Remaining Work**, **Completed Work**

I'd like to add an option to add **completed work** hours on check-in.  Currently default pending changes screen looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do is to add a textbox next to each workitem that will update total complete hours of the task upon check-in.

1. Is there anything available out of the box?
2. If not, is it possible to use TFS API and modify Native pending changes page and check-in action?

Answer (score 0):

I suggets you to setup firstly Tool Productivity TFS (Link based on TFS2012)

link : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd

So you can use `Process Editor` (It's Add In visual studio) in order to `customize Work Item Types` for adding new field total complete hours.

sample link : http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/1/how-to-customize-tfs-2010-work-items-and-workflows/